# Exit Column Section To Continue Normal Editing

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer, text-formatting

Using OpenOffice.Org on OSX 10.5.8 I typed text into my page, using my regular document parameters/margins, then I inserted a "section" so that what I typed in next could be entered in 2 columns.

I have finished entering the text in those columns and would like to enter the remainder of my text across the full width of the page, but I can't seem to get the cursor to locate itself outside of the column section I inserted.

How do I exit from the 2 column "section" in order to type the rest of my text? In the example below, my cursor is stuck in "text group #2", but I still need to enter the text that belongs in "text group #3" and cannot figure out how to exit the column section in order to do that.

I want the final page layout to look like this:

```
(Text group #1)

jsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhasd
fjddkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekha
dkfjdkjshekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhasd
fjdkjsdkfherjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethw
ejthwekh

(Text group #2 in Section that I had to "insert" in order to make 2 columns)
wkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhjs      dkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhasdkfjdkjsdkfher
wkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhjs      dkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhasdkfjdkjsdkfher
wkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhjs      dkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhasdkfjdkjsdkfher
wkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhjs      dkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhasdkfjdkjsdkfher
wkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhjs      dkfherhekjtthwkejthwekhasdkfjdkjsdkfher

(Text group #3)
jsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhasd
fjdkdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekha
dkfjdkjshekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhasd
fjdkjsdkfherjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekhjsdkfherhekjtwakethwkejthwekh
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak for older versions, but in current versions of OpenOffice (4.1.2) and LibreOffice (5.x), you just need to move the cursor the end of the section and press Alt+Enter. The newly created line will be outside the section.

(I realize that this is an old question, but as this the the first Google result I found when searching, I wanted to supply the answer I found.)

Comment: Nice spot, could you possible [edit] your answer to include a screenshot of this?

Answer (score 0):

I too am having this problem.  Not sure why.  I opened an second page to demonstrate the issue to someone in my house and the problem didn't occur.

I thought it was solved.  When I reverted to the original page, it was the same again.  Would love to find a solution.

UPDATE I:  Try copy and pasting everything to a new page.  It seems to work then.

UPDATE II:  Okay I think I figured it.

Follow these steps...
 1.  Enter desired text.
 2.  Hit [Enter] after last word / number / entry.
 3.  Then highlight the text and columnise.

This seems to break the cursor from the section to be columnised.

How NOT to do it...
 1.  Enter desired text.
 2.  Then highlight the text and columnise.

These second method seems to trap the cursor in the columned section.

Hope it helps.  Seems to be working for me.